# Order collection by property value being present in another array or collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Given the following collection:

```php
$client = Client::all();

//all: [
//    App\Models\Client {
//        #id: 1,
//        name: "Roark",
//    },
//     App\Models\Client {
//        #id: 2,
//        name: "Tanika",
//    },
//    App\Models\Client {
//        #id: 3,
//        name: "Max",
//    },
//     App\Models\Client {
//        #id: 4,
//        name: "Sloane",
//    },
//],
```

and an array for order priority base on **id** property:

```php
$priority = [2,3];
```

I would like to order (sort) the collection and end up with the following order:

```php
    App\Models\Client {
        #id: 2,
        name: "Tanika",
    },
    App\Models\Client {
        #id: 3,
        name: "Max",
    },
    App\Models\Client {
        #id: 1,
        name: "Roark",
    },
    App\Models\Client {
        #id: 4,
        name: "Sloane",
    },
```

If id is not in priority list, order can remain as pulled from DB.

Ideally I would like to keep the collection as a collection and not use  `->toArray()`

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$client = $client->sortBy(
   fn($model) => in_array($model->id, $priority) 
       ? array_search($model->id, $priority) 
       : count($priority) + $model->id
);
```

using [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby) collection method.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to be working a charm!

Comment: This is a good approach because it accounts for items that are not in the sorting array. I'd recommend adding it as an answer to the dupe target.